# Error in LFE - Long Vectors Not Supported - R. 3.4.3

Tags: r

I am running a regression with a large number of factors and variables using the LFE command in the FELM package in R 3.4.3. When I include a large number of covariates and cluster the standard errors, I get the following error:

> Error in Crowsum(xz, ia) :
>     long vectors not supported yet: ../include/Rinlinedfuns.h:138

I think it is the implementation of the clustering. I have made testing, and my  routine works just fine for a relatively large number of covariates (5-8k) without the clustering. The routine works without clustering with a small number of covariates (1k).

By looking at the source code, it seems that the construction of the clustered variance-covariance matrix breaks.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vectors of 2^31 or more elements are called long vectors. Apparently either your data has, or some calculation within FELM produces a long vector which are not supported. Not much more to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added more details to the question.