# FE Regression Produces Long Vectors - R.3.5.0

Tags: r

The problem:

I am estimating fixed effects models using the `felm` function in the `lfe` package. I estimate several models, but the largest includes approximately 40 dependent variables plus county and year fixed effects (~3000 levels and 14 levels, respectively) using ~50 million observations. When I run the model, I get the following error:

```
Error in Crowsum(xz, ia) :
  long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:519
Calls: felm -> felm.mm -> newols -> Crowsum
```

I realize that long vectors contain 2^31 or more elements, so I assume that `felm` produces these long vectors in estimating the model. Details about my resources: I have access to high-performance computing with multiple nodes, each with multiple cores; the node with the largest memory has 1012GB.

(1) Is support for "long vectors" something that can only be added by the author of `lfe` package?

(2) If so, are there other options for FE regressions on large data (provided that one has access to large amounts of memory and/or cluster computing, as I do)? (If I need to make a separate post to address this question more specifically, I can do that as well.)

---

Please note that I know there is a similar post about this problem: [Error in LFE - Long Vectors Not Supported - R. 3.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480427/error-in-lfe-long-vectors-not-supported-r-3-4-3)

However, I made a new question for two reasons: (1) the author's question was unfocused--unclear what feedback to provide and I didn't want to assume that what I wanted to know was the same as the author; and (2) even if I edited the question, the original author left out details that I thought could be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that long vectors won't be supported by the `lfe` package unless the author adds support.

Other routes for performing regression analysis with large datasets include the `biglm` package. `biglm` lets you run linear or logistic regression on a chunk, and then update the regression estimates as you run the regression on further chunks. However, this is a sequential process--which means it cannot be performed in parallel--and thus may run into memory issues (or take too long).

Another option, if you have access to some advanced computing resources (more cores, more RAM) is to use the `partools` package which provides tools for working with R's `parallel`. The package provides a wrapper for R's `lm` called `calm` (chunk averaged linear model), which, similar to `biglm` regresses on chunks, but allows for the process to be done in parallel. The vignette for `partools` is an excellent resources for learning how to use the package (even for those who haven't used the `parallel` package before): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partools/index.html

It appears that `calm` doesn't report standard errors, but datasets of the size that require parallel computing, standard errors probably are not relevant -- especially so if that dataset contains data from the entire population being studied.